# Event ID 4732 when user got added to Builtin/Users group

Tags: windows

I'm having a difficult time understanding why windows event id 4732 (A member was added to a security-enabled local group) got triggered whenever a new user was added to: group: Users, group domain name: builtin. So I guess this means they were added to the group `Builtin\Users`.

After reading more about builtin\Users, it seems like it's all the users that the OS creates when installing the OS including local accounts.

1. Why is builtin\Users considered a security enabled group?
2. Is this event supposed to trigger everytime a new, non-administrative user is added to the system?
3. If we get this event after an account is newly created, is it considered a new local admin account or domain account?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, they are a default group that gets added when an active directory domain is set up, which enables them to log in, do backups, and other tasks associated with the group.

> Many default groups are automatically assigned a set of user rights that authorize members of the group to perform specific actions in a domain, such as logging on to a local system or backing up files and folders. For example, a member of the Backup Operators group has the right to perform backup operations for all domain controllers in the domain.

> Default groups are located in the Builtin container and in the Users container in Active Directory Users and Computers. The Builtin container includes groups that are defined with the Domain Local scope. The Users includes contains groups that are defined with Global scope and groups that are defined with Domain Local scope. You can move groups that are located in these containers to other groups or organizational units (OU) within the domain, but you cannot move them to other domains.

Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/active-directory-security-groups

Comment: If we get this event after an account is newly created, is it considered a new local admin account or domain account?